# Artifactory REST API: how to add/append docker image artifacts to Build Info?

Tags: json, rest, artifactory

I have a bamboo server that builds docker images and pushes them to artifactory via reverse proxy. Since the push from the reverse proxy (NGINX) does not provide build information, I need to create it for further requirements.

I came across this REST API https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-build-info-json-file-via-the-rest-api/

That went very fine, but the problem is that, when I go to the web UI and check for the build, for every artifact it appears only the name, and even the type, but the "Repo Path" column, shows "No path found (externally resolved or deleted/overwritten)".

Via appending artifacts to an existing module (/api/build/append), or creating a new build (like in the link above), my modules section looks like:

```
[{
  "id":"my-module",
  "artifacts":[
    {
      "type": "txt",
      "sha1": "73f4617b4a64dc95c63581609ea0734aab987d98",
      "md5": "00ebbb0b0444645b9489825d7a11c4bf",
      "name": "MyArtifact.txt"
     }
  ]
}]
```

The artifact json was created looking at the attributes of the artifacts pushed by the reverse proxy.

In short, I want to create build info linked to artifacts that are already uploaded into artifactory.

1. Any ideas why this isn't correctly linking the artifacts to the
   build info?
2. Do I need any extra attributes?
3. Is it really possible to do what I'm looking for?

I'm not using JFrog's artifactory client for my task. I'm just using Advanced Rest Client for testing commands, and jersey client from my java classes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and finally found some of their source code.  It appears that artifacts are linked via properties.

So If your build info name is Test and the build info number is 1

You need to add the following properties to MyArtifact.txt

build.name = Test
build.number = 1

I also believe that you need to publish your build info after these properties have been added to the artifact

Comment: Thank you man, you saved my life! The artifactory documentation had this in notes: "Notes: All build modules must have the build.name and build.number properties set as well as the correct SHA1 and MD5 in order to be properly linked in the build info." but it did not translate in my head that I need to update every single artifact with the properties. This should be marked as proper answer.